# Generating a password protected PDF with hyperlinks with the Aspose.Pdf library

Tags: c#, .net, aspose, aspose.pdf

I’m hoping someone can help me with a problem I’m having with generating a password protected PDF with hyperlinks with the Aspose.Pdf library. The problem is that the password protection seems to screw the hyperlink up …

The following code works fine (without any password protection):

```
// create new PDF doc with hyperlink in
Aspose.Pdf.Document doc = new Aspose.Pdf.Document();
Aspose.Pdf.Page page = doc.Pages.Add();
Aspose.Pdf.Text.TextFragment textFragment = new Aspose.Pdf.Text.TextFragment("hyperlink test");
textFragment.Hyperlink = new Aspose.Pdf.WebHyperlink("https://www.google.co.uk/");
page.Paragraphs.Add(textFragment);

// password protect the PDF
// Aspose.Pdf.Permissions permission = (Aspose.Pdf.Permissions.PrintingQuality | Aspose.Pdf.Permissions.PrintDocument | Aspose.Pdf.Permissions.ModifyTextAnnotations | Aspose.Pdf.Permissions.FillForm | Aspose.Pdf.Permissions.ModifyContent | Aspose.Pdf.Permissions.ExtractContent | Aspose.Pdf.Permissions.AssembleDocument);
// doc.Encrypt("pass1", "pass2", permission, Aspose.Pdf.CryptoAlgorithm.RC4x128);

// save the doc
doc.Save("C:\\temp\\PDFHyperlink\\test.pdf");
```

The PDF that is generated is fine with the hyperlink successfully opening a browser and navigating to google

[image]

However, if you uncomment the lines that password protect the PDF, the hyperlinks are screwed up

```
// create new PDF doc with hyperlink in
Aspose.Pdf.Document doc = new Aspose.Pdf.Document();
Aspose.Pdf.Page page = doc.Pages.Add();
Aspose.Pdf.Text.TextFragment textFragment = new Aspose.Pdf.Text.TextFragment("hyperlink test");
textFragment.Hyperlink = new Aspose.Pdf.WebHyperlink("https://www.google.co.uk/");
page.Paragraphs.Add(textFragment);

// password protect the PDF
Aspose.Pdf.Permissions permission = (Aspose.Pdf.Permissions.PrintingQuality | Aspose.Pdf.Permissions.PrintDocument | Aspose.Pdf.Permissions.ModifyTextAnnotations | Aspose.Pdf.Permissions.FillForm | Aspose.Pdf.Permissions.ModifyContent | Aspose.Pdf.Permissions.ExtractContent | Aspose.Pdf.Permissions.AssembleDocument);
doc.Encrypt("pass1", "pass2", permission, Aspose.Pdf.CryptoAlgorithm.RC4x128);

// save the doc
doc.Save("C:\\temp\\PDFHyperlink\\test.pdf");
```

[image]

… and you get the following message when the hyperlink is clicked:

[image]

… and if you click **Allow**, nothing happens!

Is there a problem with the way I’m password protecting the PDF? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the scenario and have managed to reproduce above stated issue. For the sake of correction, I have logged it as **PDFNET-41159** in our issue tracking system. We will further look into the details of this problem and will keep you updated on the status of correction. Please be patient and wait for the resolution.

*My name is Nayyer and I am developer evangelist at Aspose.*